# Pact JS - How to send request body for state change?

Tags: pact

I don't see a way to pass the body for stateChange call using pact.io JavaScript version. For the JVM version ConsumerPactBuilder.given() takes two parameters, the state name and a map of params. However, I do not see an equivalent for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [v3 spec feature](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-specification/tree/version-3), which is currently not supported in other languages (Just JVM and Rust at the moment). We are working on v3 compatibility in other languages, but it's not yet complete.